# dispatch action to close modal

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have reducer which hides and display a modal component;

```
import {SHOW_MODAL, HIDE_MODAL } from '../constants/ActionTypes'


import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import * as actions from '../actions';

const initialState = {
  modalType: null,
  modalProps: {}
}

export default function modal(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOW_MODAL':
      return {
        modalType: action.modalType,
        modalProps: action.modalProps
      }
    case 'HIDE_MODAL':
      return initialState
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Action that shows modal:

```
export const showAchievement = (modalProps) => ({ type: types.SHOW_ACHIEVEMENT, ...modalProps })
```

How can I send a function to my modal component that will dispatch an action `'HIDE_MODAL'` :

```
  openAchievementModal(){
        this.props.showAchievement({
           type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
          modalType: 'ADD_ACHIEVEMENT',
          modalProps: {
          dayId: this.props.day.id,
          onChange: this.props.addAchievement
        }
    })
  }
```

I am using `react-modal` as wrapper for my modals which are mounted at the top of components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import ModalWrapper from './ModalWrapper.js';

import Select from 'react-select';

export default class AddAchievementModal extends Component {

   constructor() {
       super();
         this.logChange = this.logChange.bind(this);
  }

  logChange(e) {

        this.props.onChange(this.props.dayId, e.label)
        this.props.onClose()
  }

  render() {

    console.log(this.props)
    var options = [
      { value: 1, label: 'Play Music' },
      { value: 2, label: 'Football' }
    ];

    return (
         <span >
          <ModalWrapper
            onRequestClose={this.props.closeModal}
            style={this.props.customStyles}
            contentLabel="Modal" >

          <h2>Add Achievement</h2>

          <Select
            name="form-field-name"
            value="one"
            options={options}
            onChange={this.logChange}
          />
          </ModalWrapper>
      </span>
    )

    }
}
```

React modal wrapper:

```
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const customStyles = {
  content : {
    top                   : '50%',
    left                  : '50%',
    right                 : '50%',
    bottom                : '30%',
    marginRight           : '-50%',
    transform             : 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    borderRadius          : '10px',
    border                : '3px solid #ccc'
  },
};

class ModalWrapper extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: true
    };

    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  }


   render() {
    return (
          <Modal style={customStyles}  isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen} contentLabel="Model Wrapper" closeModal={this.props.closeModal}>
                <header>
                <button onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
                 </header>

                {this.props.children}

           </Modal>
          );
  }
}

export default ModalWrapper
```

To close the modal, do I need to `modelIsOpen` to false, aswell as dispatching an action `HIDE_MODAL` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `actions` should be plain objects; you are mixing them with functions.

What you should instead do is to only pass the `callback` functions which dispatch actions to the `modal` component.

You would do this in the *smart* component. See [smart-and-dumb-components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) article.

```
onOpenAchievementModal() {
  this.props.showAchievement({
    ...
  })
}

onAddAchievementModal(achievement) {
  this.props.addAchievement({
    ...
    achievement,
  })
}
```

and then render the modal, something like:

```
<Modal onOpen={this.onOpenAchievementModal} onClickAchievement={this.onAddAchievementModal}/>
```

Comment: thanks, do I need my modal reducer aswell as my `react-modal` wrapper?

Comment: The question is: do you need/want to track the modal state in the redux store? If not, you can get rid of redux here and use component state.